# Sample 3rd Party APIs to practice Salesforce Apex callouts

Tags: rest-api, json, callout

Are there any sample 3rd party APIs that I could make use for practicing Salesforce Apex callouts.

Answer (score 1):

[Requestb.in](http://requestb.in/) works very well for testing Apex callouts - it will show you the content of your request. Use https://requestbin.herokuapp.com for HTTPS.

[Yahoo Weather API](https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/) will give you JSON or XML formatted weather data.

[Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) will give you latitude/longitude for addresses - you could populate the geolocation fields on an Account in a future method called from a trigger.

[Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/api) is great for SMS (and voice) - you can callout to send SMS messages, and expose an endpoint to receive them.

Comment: @metadaddy I was wondering if there were more like a raw APIs. As I would want to use them to invoke in Apex controllers to make the insert/view its data in Salesforce objects. 

The referral links that you've provided didn't have that ability or I might I misunderstood them.

Comment: You're right - Requestb.in only lets you test that your callout is successfully hitting the endpoint - it doesn't give you any other useful data in response. I'll update my answer with more options.

Comment: The modified links seems to be resourceful and helpful. I started to work on them (as a beginner) and shall reach out if needed any further information.